# How to acess parent report field from subreport?

Tags: jasper-reports

Is there a syntax to access parent report field from subreport in *JasperReports* expression ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot access parent report data from subreport directly. You have to pass the datasource of the main report as a parameter into the subreport (or even as the datasource of the subreport, if you do not need another one).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that. But that depends on where you want to access it. In formula creator, you can always access fields of opened form. For example you open form on record 10. Your form is called Users. It is still open and you open report. In report you can access fields of user form.

There are few ways to do that and I need exact description what you are trying to achieve in order to help you. But here is how you can discover path to field in expression builder.

[image]

It is in Russian but I'll explain.

1. Navigate to your DB currently opened forms or reports
2. Select field
3. Double click `<value>` and path to field will be inserted into expression builder. You can start from there.